# What is the status of the Mercurial Shallow Clone extension?

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-extension, shallow-clone

**Talk of Shallow Clone Extension**

There had been some talk about work on an unofficial Shallow Clone extension for Mercurial.  This extension would function similarly to the `git clone --depth X` extension, but would provide better push support and merge safety.

Basically, it would let users clone a smaller sub-set of history to save time and space, but still benefit from all the other benefits of hg.  After all, not all developers need the whole history back to changeset 0 to be productive.

**Links to Discussions**

The [Shallow Clone extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ShallowClone) is discussed on hg's site.  They also put up a [status page](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ShallowCloneStatus) and a [plan for implementation](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ShallowClonePlan).  Furthermore, they repeatedly mention that they got a Google Summer of Code (gsoc) intern to work on the extension in the summer of 2010.

Even still, I can't seem to find any up to date status on this feature.  I found two bitbucket projects that may be related to it, but neither has seen any recent commits: [hg-shallow-clone](https://bitbucket.org/vsh/hg-shallow-clone/changesets) and [hg-shallow](https://bitbucket.org/parren/hg-shallow/changesets).

**Is Shallow Clone Still Under Development?**

Does anyone know that status of this extension?  Is it still being worked on somewhere by someone or is it truly abandoned?  What ever came of that GSoC work?

Comment: Why don't you just ask the Mercurial developers if you're interested in this subject? You do that by sending a mail to mercurial-devel@selenic.com -- the mailinglist for Mercurial development. You wont even have to subscribe first.

Comment: Thank @MartinGeisler. I might, but it looks like Ry4an may have the answer after all.

Comment: Yeah, he has an answer -- we both do since we follow the Mercurial development on the mailinglists. My point is that you're dilluting the mailinglists when you ask questions here that could better be answered there. Posting on StackOverflow is not the right way to contact the Mercurial developers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not under development.  Various people from outside the Mercurial project have made attempts, but none have come to fruition, and the Mercurial project itself considers things like the largefiles extension a better solution for keeping repository clone sizes down.

Comment: Hey @Ry4an, that's good to know.  I actually don't want the feature to keep repo sizes down, but because my company is hesitant of putting a full copy of the history on each developer machine because they think it could be a security risk.  I know that's a lower priority for the big DVCS projects, but I thought I'd ask.